# the meaning of "archness"

Tags: meaning

*Kojève had a famous sense of humor and here, as in many of his letters and interviews, it is not entirely clear how serious he is being. But beneath the irony and **archness** Strauss saw something that, while it earned his intellectual respect, also horrified him.*

Could you tell me the meaning of "archness" in the context of the above clause. Does it mean some figure of speech or something similar?

Comment: See Collins s.v. [**arch**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/arch), adj. 4. playfully or affectedly roguish or mischievous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'm posting an answer as this sense of *arch* is relatively uncommon, and may be difficult to suss directly from the dictionary.]

*Archness* is *arch* plus the suffix *[-ness](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ness)* which indicates a noun representing the quality or nature of being something. But this adjective meaning of *arch* has nothing to do with curves or with superiority.

The [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/arch_3) and [Cambridge Dicionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arch#british-1-3-1) definitions of *arch* are substantially similar to that of the [Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/arch_3):

> speaking or looking as though you think it is funny that you know something that someone else does not know

This strikes me as somewhat narrow to pair with *irony*, but the meaning is more explicit in other references. The [American Heritage Dictionary definition](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=arch) is

> a. Mischievous; roguish; b. Teasing, ironic, or sardonic

The [Merriam-Webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archness) definition is

> a.  mischievous, saucy; b.  marked by a deliberate and often forced playfulness, irony, or impudence

Perhaps, then *archness* is more than *cleverness* — it is a writer's cleverness plus a self-satisfaction with the cleverness; Kojève was perhaps too pleased with his own way with words. The writer of the passage says that despite this literary equivalent of a [smirk](https://twitter.com/thehill/status/695458956207091712), Strauss perceived a serious side to Kojève's writing.